# qgis 2.18.25 ltr plugins not loading

Tags: qgis, plugins

I cannot download any of the plugins from the drop down menu, plugin installation failed. I have tried the re networking and also manual download but have not been able to find an answer for which folder to place ity into for this version of qgis. I am running Win10 pro. 
Any help would be good.

Comment: Ok the new ltr has just been released and plugins are downloading ok using this version. Happy for this question to be closed.